# Husky failed to install cannot read property of 'toString' of null

Tags: npm, githooks, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, husky

I have an issue installing husky (with lint-staged) for a while now and I would very much appreciate any help. My project setup is: node JS, npm with eslint, prettier set-up and now trying to add husky with lint-staged.

**THE MAIN ISSUE:**

When installing husky "npm install husky --save-dev" the pre-commit file (in ".git/hooks" folder) is not being modified with Husky code! The installation message:

```
husky > Setting up git hooks
Cannot read property 'toString' of null
husky > Failed to install
```

System details:
OS: Windows 10
Git: git version 2.28.0
node -v
v12.16.1
husky: 4.2.5

I have tried the following:
(1 Git is registered as an env PATH variable
(2 There is no hooksPath set in the global gitconfig file that would point to another directory than .git/hooks in the local workspace
(3 Installing/uninstalling Husky
(4 Making the pre-commit file executable by removing .sample
(5 Deleting .git/hooks/pre-commit file altogether
(6 Adding the necessary script in the "package.json" file as below

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.js": "eslint --fix",
    "*.{html,md,json}": "prettier --write"
  }
```

I have still no luck.

As a consequence, when committing changes, husky does NOT run at all!

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest going here: https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/655